# 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code ""

Tags: php, email, yii, yii2, smtp

I have a such code for sending mail via SMTP

```
if (isset ($_POST['Message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['url']."
    :".$_POST["Message"];
    $message0 = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
    \Yii::$app->mailer->useFileTransport=false;
    \Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'mail.myhost.com',
        'username' => 'info@myhost.com',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'port' => '25',
    ]);
    $message = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
    $contentEncoder7bit = new \Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_PlainContentEncoder('7bit');
    $message->getSwiftMessage()->setEncoder($contentEncoder7bit);
    \Swift_MimePart::newInstance();
    $message->setFrom('info@myhost.com')
        ->setTo('korrektor@mail.com')
        ->setSubject('Sunbject')
        ->setTextBody($message0);
    $message->send();
    return;
}
```

while triyng to send mail I get error below

```
exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""'  in
C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(289):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('', Array) 
#1 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(117):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting() 
#2 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(79):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() 
#3 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-swiftmailer\Mailer.php(146): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) 
#4 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMailer.php(262): yii\swiftmailer\Mailer->sendMessage(Object(yii\swiftmailer\Message)) 
#5 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMessage.php(48): yii\mail\BaseMailer->send(Object(yii\swiftmailer\Message)) 
#6 C:\wamp\www\yii\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php(1982): yii\mail\BaseMessage->send() 
#7 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionSendorphus() 
#8 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#9 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array) 
#10 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('sendorphus', Array) 
#11 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/sendorphus', Array) 
#12 C:\wamp\www\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request)) 
#13 C:\wamp\www\yii\frontend\web\index.php(19): yii\base\Application->run() 
#14 {main}
```

Comment: If there is no response code it generally means that swiftmailer could not connect to the smtp server. So check if you can connect to the server given in the config from a mailer client(Mozilla Thunderbird for example)

Comment: katona.abel, yes, password was not appropriate